# Separating AES/CBC IV and ciphertext in one message

Tags: python, encryption, data-structures, messaging

Most examples on stackoverflow and the web at large put the CBC initialization vector (IV) as a "prefix" to ciphertext, e.g.:

```
bytesToSend = bytesOfIV + bytesOfCipherText
```

And then on the other side, a variety of clever/simple/flexible means are used to separate them, the slicing operator in python and assuming a 16 byte IV being particularly prevalent (and simple):

```
bytesRead = get bytes from source
IV = bytesRead[:16]
cipherText = bytesRead[16:]
```

This approach has stood the test of time and it's fine but it also is very limiting in that both sides (specifically, the listener part of both sides) must know **exactly** what they should do with the inbound bytes.  In fact, short of slicing off the IV and using the shared secret, there's almost no other operation that can be performed.
I am examining a design wherein inbound messages have two sections: one that can be encrypted and one that is NEVER encrypted.   Clearly, sensitive information is NOT put into the unencrypted section, but because it is in plaintext, a listener can actually do something intelligent with the content **prior** to decryption.  Example: message routing, identifiers for multiple encryption keys, etc.   And of course, this could include the IV.  Simplified example:

```
{
  neverEncrypted:  {
    cipher: "AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING",
    IV: "121866AFBBDF2906C0D942C1FA7C4DAB",
    other: [ "hello", 2, 3 ],
    timestamp:  date
  },
  data: (binary cipherText WITHOUT the IV prefix)
}
```

This approach certainly "works" and IV is not assumed to be secret so it can live in `neverEncrypted`.   I also like the fact that one does not have to get "clever" about the concatenation and splitting of material, esp. assumptions about block size initialization, etc.  This is particularly true if a listener needs to listen for material encrypted with 2 (or more) ciphers.

The question is: Is there any **special advantage** to the "prefix" approach re. security or is it more just a nice method of transferring both pieces of information without requiring any additional fancy data structure decoding?

Answer (score 3):

In terms of security, no, there are no direct benefits from prefixing the IV to the ciphertext (other than the ease of HMACing which I talk about below).  The design you've outlined is just as secure (provided a correct implementation) as prefixing the IV.

There are definitely benefits in efficiency, however.  Consider the resource cost of parsing and structuring a JSON object in memory versus the cost of splitting a stream of bytes.  The latter is astronomically faster.  You wouldn't notice this though unless you're processing very large amounts of data.

As long as your crypto implementation is correct, how you transfer parameters isn't really that important as long as both endpoints know what to do with the data.

Note that your suggested method might prove more difficult to HMAC your ciphertext properly as you need to apply the HMAC to the IV and ciphertext, hence why having an IV prefixed ciphertext is easier.

Comment: Agree on all points.   The JSON-esque setup was a representative example of rich structure; there are def ways to express same without parsing.